# Google Maps API, distance from metro stations

Tags: javascript, list, google-maps, distance

How can I get the list of e.g 3 nearest metro stations from specified point and the distance from the point to station?

Comment: Did u get a soution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have t use the [Google Local Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html) in order to retrive the locations closer to your point.